# Adding multi-route labels at transit centers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

Is there anyway to make ArcMap produce labels like this:

[image]

without doing it manually?

I need to create a 'grid' of labels' where otherwise a mess of conflicting/overlapping labels would show?

I've never used Maplex, don't know what it is, or even if it still exists in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

Comment: The Maplex Labeling Engine was long ago licensed separately as an extension. For the last 10-15 years it has been part of the core product and available to all three license levels.

Comment: I think you’ll need to use ArcPy to do this. Each “grid of labels” would need to be based on a calculated point location and generated from attribute values using a preprocessing step that determines what lines/routes intersect at a point.